Determining AD group memberships for multiple PC's at a time
My goal is to be able to quickly compare group memberships applied to multiple PCs to confirm that they are all members of exactly the same groups.
For starters, I apologize as I have very limited experience with PowerShell, and there is likely a very easy solution to my problem.
I'm defining my PC's simply by expressing them as a variable:
$Computers = "pc1", "pc2", "pc3" 

I'm then piping them into another cmd:
$computers | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership 

While this does return all of the groups that all PCs are a member of, the output only lists the groups but not which PCs belong to which groups.  As mentioned, I'm hoping I see the group memberships of each PC individually.
I sincerely appreciate any advice offered!

What you can do instead is use $Computers | Get-ADComputer -Properties MemberOf then you can see each computer membership by inspecting the .MemberOf property but it's unclear what you're expecting as a result of the comparison

What you could do is loop over each computer in your array and for each of these, loop over the groups it is a member of.
Next, output objects with both the computer name and the group (one item per group).
For comparison later, I'd suggest you save the results as CSV file you can double-click to open in Excel.
$Computers = "pc1", "pc2", "pc3" 
$computers | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($group in (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_)) {
        [PsCustomObject] @{
            ComputerName = $_
            Group        = $group.Name
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\ComputerGroupMembers.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

